# How can I give more than one value to a single cell with a static word in the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a editable html table, and I would like to know how can I give more than one value to a single cell with a static word in the middle, example:

I have this already:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Days</th>
    <th>Work Schedule</th>
    <th>Rest and Meal Interval</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>This is editable</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I would like to have this:

[image]

So the word `às` will always be in the middle of those cells, and I need a space before and after it to write some values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something in the same column, you'll need to change the `td` to contain two inputs and the text between, something like this:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40%;
  
  height: 100%
}

span {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Days</th>
    <th>Work Schedule</th>
    <th>Rest and Meal Interval</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td><input type="text"/><span>às</span><input type="text"/></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
    <td contenteditable='true'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously some additional CSS will be needed to make it look pretty.